# Discrete Probability problem with a formula?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Assume that it's observed that in each episode of The Simpsons, the probability that Homer will say "D'oh!" $k$ times is $\dfrac{1}{2^{k+1}}$.
>
> Today you are going to watch a new episode:
>
> $\text{(a)}$ What is the probability that Homer will express his annoyance at least twice?
>
> $\text{(b)}$ What is the expected number of times he will do that during the episode?

I have an idea about $a)$. Basically since the question ask about the probability that Homer will express his annoyance at least twice, which means $2$ times or more. The "opposite" of this is that Homer will express his annoyance less than twice which is once(and the expression can't equal to $0$). So the formula gives $\frac{1}{2 ^{( 1 + 1)}}$ or $0.25$. Then the actual probability is $1- 0.25=0.75$. Is this correct?

$b)$ I don't have any thoughts on how answer this part. Any ideas would be very nice.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: For the first part you're not counting on the possibility of $k=0$ case not happening. For the 2nd part, define a discrete random variable $X$ taking on values from $k=0,1,2,\dots$ with probability $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$. What is it's Expectation?

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. O time means probability of 1/2. SO how do I combine the probability for 0 times and 1 times. Do I just add 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75 ? Then 1- 0.75 = 0.25 as the answer?

Comment: Yes you're right !

Answer (score 0):

a) Your idea is good, but it *is* possible that Homer expresses his anger $0$ times.

b) Recall the definition of expectation.